# not able to post on facebook from my iOS application when facebook application is already installed on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook sdk version 2.0 in my iOS application to post on facebook.

I am able to post on facebook when facebook app is NOT installed on the device . However I am unable to post when facebook app is installed .

Kindly help since it is a very crucial module in my application.

Comment: integrate latest facebookSDK in your project 3.5

Comment: is it not possible with the current SDK version that I am using ?

Comment: we i mot using 2.0 i done with new sdk that's why i suggest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

The delegate method in Facebook.m

- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth

contains a Bool didOpenOtherApp which indicates whether the facebook app should be opened or not

didOpenOtherApp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbAppUrl]];

if false , the facebook api will always open inside your application. I have commented the code so that the bool will always have value false